# Understanding when Ruby changes string into Unicode representation

Tags: ruby, unicode

I'd like to know why Ruby is representing my returned value differently in the scenario below. I'm sending a function a list of equations and immediately returning it as is. If printed directly, ≡ shows up as its Unicode sequence instead. If I index into the result, it shows as ≡ again. I get `true` when testing if the Unicode sequence is equivalent to ≡, so I'm not concerned the value changed. I'd just like to know why it prints differently to the screen.

```
def Explain(equations)
  equations
end

equations = ["x≡3(mod4)", "x≡4(mod5)"]

puts "ORIGINAL LIST"
equations.each { |e| puts e }

puts "\n\nRETURNED AS A LIST"
puts Explain(equations).to_s

puts "\n\nRETURNED AND ACCESSED INDIVIDUALLY"
puts Explain(equations)[0]
puts Explain(equations)[1]
```

Outputs:

```
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]

ORIGINAL LIST
x≡3(mod4)
x≡4(mod5)


RETURNED AS A LIST
["x\u22613(mod4)", "x\u22614(mod5)"]


RETURNED AND ACCESSED INDIVIDUALLY
x≡3(mod4)
x≡4(mod5)
```

Comment: In Ruby capital letters have significant meaning. Method and variable names should be lower-case only, so this method should be `explain`, not `Explain`. Capital letters are reserved for `ClassName` and `CONSTANT_NAME` situations.

Comment: Ruby 2.3.1 produces `["x≡3(mod4)", "x≡4(mod5)"]`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not "changing to Unicode representation", it's changing to `inspect` representation. `puts` calls `to_s` on the given argument(s) in order to present them, and by default Array just shows up in its "raw" form.

Printing individual elements produces the desired behaviour because that's a simple string. Printing the array itself is problematic because the array will show up using `.inspect`.

Try this:

```
puts equations.join(' ')
```

Where that combines them with a space and everything looks fine.

Note: The `\u...` notation is used when any non-ASCII characters appear in a string when a string is "inspected". The same goes for things like `\n` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is happening when you call to_s on an array. It converts each of the values in the array to a uniform ascii based string.